# Where is installed JDK 1.7 on mac

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a problem with Android Studio "Gradle project sync failed" it also says compileSdkVersion android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7. I have installed jdk-7u71 then running in the terminal usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7 tells me the JDK is in /Libary/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Content/Home unlike v 1.6 which is in System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine, however when I go on finder I can't find the Java folder in Library. Also when I add the path to JDK location in the Android Studio I get an error saying Please choose a valid JDK directory. Where is this jdk1.7.0_71.jdk then?

Answer (score 1):

According to my mac, my JDK folder is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/
```

You may find it there. If you cannot, try to reinstall it.